# Qual é a diferença entre o comportamento de um método estático, método normal e método da classe?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando python com OOP e as vezes me sinto confuso de quando utilizar determinado método.

```
class MeuObjeto(object):

    def __init__(self, objeto):
        self.objeto = objeto

    def metodo_normal(self): //sem decorator
       pass

    @staticmethod
    def metodo_estatico():
       pass

    @classmethod
    def metodo_da_classe(cls):
       pass
```

O que eu mais entendi é o classmethod, sempre que quero instanciar um objeto da classe eu devo utiliza-la, porém as demais estão me deixando confuso.

Comment: Rafael, só lembre-se que o método deve receber como primeiro parâmetro o `self` e o método de classe o `cls`. Na pergunta você colocou todos sem argumentos e isso se tornaria inválido.

Comment: bem observado @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quanto a sua confusão:

Em quase todos os casos, você precisa de um "método normal": isso é - 
um método de instância, sem nenhum decorador, que vai receber o "self" - uma instância da classe, como primeiro parâmetro.

Um método de classe - que é criado com o decorador `@classmethod`, pode ser usado diretamente a partir do nome da classe - não de uma instância - no seu exemplo, significa que é possível fazer:

```
MeuObjeto.metodo_da_classe()
```

diretamente, enquanto que para o método normal, é necessário

```
obj = MeuObjeto()
obj.metodo_normal
```

Python passa no primeiro parâmetro de um método de classe a própria classe - por isso, por convenção, o nome do primeiro parâmetro é "cls". Assim como o "self" é por convenção também - não há uma regra da linguagem que limite o nome desses parâmetros, e é normal, em decoradores, ou dependendo do estilo de código encontrar métodos com a assinatura `*args, **kwargs` - nesse caso, o primeiro parâmetro vai vir como primeiro elemento de `args`.

Métodos de classe tem mais sentido justamente quando se deseja formas diferentes de criar objetos da classe - são frequentemente "construtores alternativos". Eles podem ser chamados a partir de uma instância também - o Python automaticamente vai colocar a classe, e não a instância, no primeiro parâmetro.

Vamos supor que você tivesse uma classe Tabela que é iniciada por uma "lista de listas" recebida no `__init__`. Poderia ter um método de classe `from_csv` que lesse um arquivo CSV e criasse uma "Tabela" com os dados lidos do arquivo CSV. É um desenho muito melhor do que colocar um monte de parâemtros opcionais no `__init__`, mas que por outro lado, pode não ter muitas vantagens sobre uma função  criada como `def nova_tabela_a_partir_de_csv(caminho_do_csv):` - que lesse o arquivo e criasse a nova `Tabela` com os dados lidos.

Há outros usos - por exemplo, no meu projeto "terminedia", a classe Blockchars_ serve basicamente para agrupar algumas estruturas de dados e funções que usam as mesmas, no mesmo lugar  -a classe tem essencialmente o mesmo papel que um módulo Python, mas, fazendo o uso de classmethods, todos os membros que ela precisa ficam agrupados no corpo da classe. A exceção é o método especial `__contains__`, que exite que a classe seja instânciada - confira o código em https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/master/terminedia.py#L204

Já os métodos estáticos, criados em Python como `@staticmethod`, acredito que sequer tem algo correspondente na teoria de orientação a objetos - uma função marcada como "staticmethod" no corpo de uma classe é simplesmente uma função - o Python não vai passar nenhum parâmetro a mais quando ela for chamada - nem a instância, nem a classe - todos os parâmetros devem ser fornecidos por quem usa a função.

A única coisa que acontece é que ela fica "guardada" dentro da classe. qualquer método que, embora tenha operações relacionadas ao objeto, não precise de nenhum dado do objeto nem da classe, poderia ser um `staticmethod` - mas as vezes sequer faz sentido ficar declarando `staticmethods` - o método pode ser deixado como normal ou método de classe mesmo.

Ainda no projeto `terminedia` eu tenho alguns métodos desse tipo - o próprio "print" interno em https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/55f830e714208c978f36adc117c56804f8e92706/terminedia.py#L307 , só usa o `self` para chamar a si mesmo recursivamente, no caso de falha - poderia perfeitamente ser uma função estática que chamasse `ScreenComands.print` - já que nenhum atributo da instância, ou outro método é chamado. Mas isso só seria uma "pedra" na arquitetura - funcionaria como está, mas se amanhã eu faço uma adaptação dessa classe pra funcionar simultaneamente em vários terminais, e precisar de instâncias distintas do "ScreenCommands", um staticmethod aí iria parar de funcionar.

Em resumo, via de regra, o melhor é não usar `@staticmethod`  a não ser que você saiba exatamente o que está fazendo (e nesse caso, vai se dar conta de que não precisa)

Comment: Agora ficou um pouco mais claro @jsbueno . Muito obrigado